# How to return data back to Facebook Messenger Bot from a WebView?

Tags: facebook, chat, bots

I've successfully implemented a WebView and then closed it.  However, I can't figure out how to return the value/data back to the FB Messenger bot.

Can someone share their experiences with this?

Comment: Same question here!

Comment: I wish there was a way to do this. I haven't found one yet. Pls let me know if this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, I am pretty sure you can't do that. Technically, you can use the share functionality to send the data back, however, the format is a bit messy and will be hard for the bot to digest.

In my experience, I use a POST end-point on the bot that would receive data from the webview and then send the result message back to the user in the messenger.